# DynamoDB query on boolean key

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm new to DynamoDB (and to noSQL in general) and am struggling a little to get my head round some of the concepts. One thing in particular is giving me some problems, which is around querying a table based on a boolean key.

I realize that I can't create a primary or secondary index on a boolean key, but I can't see how I should ideally index and query a table with the following structure;

```
reportId: string (uuid)
reportText: string
isActive: boolean
category: string
```

I would like to be able to complete the following searches:

1. Access a specific report directly (a primary hash index of `reportId`)
2. List reports of a specific category (a primary hash index on
   category)

These are both straightforward, but I would like to perform two other queries;

1. List all reports that are marked as isActive = true
2. List all reports of a specific category that are marked as isActive
   = true

My first approach would be to create a primary hashkey index on `isActive`, with a rangekey on `category`, but I'm only able to choose `String`, `Number` of `Binary` as the attribute type.

Storing `isActive` as a string (saved as 'true' rather than a boolean true) solves the problem, but its horrible using a string for a boolean property.

Am I missing something? Is there a simple way to query the table directly on a boolean value?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

My project includes this particular scenario and I've followed the DynamoDB best practice of using [sparse indexes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/BestPractices.html) on both Local and Global Secondary Indexes. Here is what I would do with your example:

```
Table: reportId (string, hash key) || reportText (string) || isActive (string, marked as "x") || category (string)

ActiveReportsIndex (Local Secondary Index): reportID (hash key) || isActive (range key)

ActiveReportsByCategoryIndex (Global Secondary Index): category (hash key) || isActive (range key) || reportId
```

The idea behind sparse indexes is that only reports marked as isActive: "x" will show up in your indexes, so they should require less storage and processing than your main table. Instead of making the isActive attribute a boolean type, which will always store a `true` or `false` value, use a string like "x" or anything else you want when the report is active and DELETE the attribute completely when the report is not active. Makes sense?

**UPDATE**: If you want a specific kind of sort when you query (e.g. chronological), use a number (e.g. a UNIX timestamp) instead of an "x" string.

Comment: This is perfect, and addresses it nicely. I hadn't seen the reference about sparse indexes (nor indeed the best practices link you included) but seems to be just what I need.

Comment: this does feel like a limitation on dynamo that you cant query based on boolean values, you have to deal with your own app logic to convert them to boolean types.

Comment: How would you create a query on the `ActiveReportsIndex` to retrieve all active reports? Wouldn't this require a scan on that index?

Comment: @SankethKatta yes, that's right. Retrieving all rows in any index or table requires a scan.

Comment: How would you query for those records that are not active?

Comment: @Oliver, you should create indexes for your specific query patterns. So, if you have a need to query for records that are not active, create a `NonActiveReportsIndex` and write an attribute called `isNotActive` on certain items that will get projected into the index.

Comment: Would a number be more efficient than an X?

Comment: @david_adler Yes, especially if you want a sort. I often throw a unix timestamp in there instead so that I can get a chronological sort when I query. I updated my answer with this. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @readyornot - to clarify, a number is more efficient because a number takes up less space and therefore an index is smaller? Do you have a link to confirm this? Extending that, would `1` be faster than a timestamp?

Comment: @david_adler - Ah, you're referring to storage efficiency. I'm sorry, but I don't know the answer to your question.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CapacityUnitCalculations.html According to this `1` would be 2 bytes and `"X"` would be 1 byte @readyornot 