# Dynamodb - how to pick appropriate GSI and LSI

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

There are  5 columns in my Table "Banners".

```
id(string) | createdAt(Date) | caption(string) | isActive(binary) | order(Int)
```

For now, id is the partition key and primary key.

In the future, I might want to do something like getting all banners with isActive =1 and sorted by order.

As far as I understand, GSI is the another option for partition key, LSI is like the second sort key with unchanged partition key in the table.

Should isActive be GSI and order be LSI?

Comment: Similar topics [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258024/dynamodb-query-on-boolean-key) and [here](https://ianding.io/2019/08/07/querying-by-boolean-values-in-dynamodb-with-gsi/). Have you seen those? [sparse indices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general-sparse-indexes.html) are also useful in such scenerios.

Comment: Yes. But i still not sure whether isActive should be GSI and order should be LSI

Answer (score 1):

Here is my rule of thumb when it comes to the LSI: only use it when you

1. need strong read consistency in the secondary index
2. want to save provisioned RCU and WCU of the secondary index

Otherwise, use the GSI without any hesitation.

Comment: Why LSI save more provisioned RCU and WCU of the secondary index than GSI? I know GSI would lead to creation of another table with different partition key. So LSI won’t do the same thing?

Comment: Also, in my use case above. What do u think the isActive/order should be set to?

Comment: @CCCC Because LSI shares RCU and WCU of the primary table. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html#LSI.ThroughputConsiderations

Comment: I would recommend GSI in general.

Comment: so you mean isActive should be partition key and order should be sort key as GSI?